# django and bootstrap 3 error with 'bootstrap_form_buttons', expected 'endblock'

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently working on a project and I want to make a nice looking login screen with django and bootstrap 3.

Atm I have this code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form role="form" method="post" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
   {% bootstrap_field form.username %}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   {% bootstrap_field form.password %}
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
   {% bootstrap_form_buttons %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
   {% end_bootstrap_form_buttons %}
</form>
</div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Which results in the following error: 
**Invalid block tag on line 20: 'bootstrap_form_buttons', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

According to me I have bootstrap3 loaded and I have looked on google but can't seem to find the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-bootstrap3` does not have a templatetag called `bootstrap_form_buttons`. You probably want to use [`buttons`](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html#buttons) or [`bootstrap_button`](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-button)

Change your code to this:

```
{% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
{% endbuttons %}
```